# Namespace packages with a core part?

Tags: python, setuptools, namespace-package

This question follows up [The way to make namespace packages in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380381/the-way-to-make-namespace-packages-in-python) and [How do I create a namespace package in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python).

Note [PEP 420](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), and the [distribute docs](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#namespace-packages), which state:

> You must NOT include any other code and data in a namespace package’s `__init__.py`. Even though it may appear to work during development, or when projects are installed as `.egg` files, it will not work when the projects are installed using “system” packaging tools – in such cases the `__init__.py` files will not be installed, let alone executed.

---

This all seems to make it impossible to have a "main library" package with independently distributed extension sub-packages. What I want is to be able to:

1. define a core library package, to be used like this:

   ```
   import mylibrary

   mylibrary.some_function()
   ```
2. allow library extensions, packaged and distributed separately, to be used like this:

   ```
   import mylibrary.myextension

   mylibrary.myextension.some_other_function()
   ```

I would've expected to be able to do this with namespace packages, but it seems not to be the case, based on the questions and links above. Can this be done at all?

Comment: I still can't believe this is still the case with modern Python. It certainly makes defining core parts for convenience in your namespace package quite "hard" :/

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed not possible to have code in a top level `__init__.py` for a PEP 420 namespace package.

If I were you, I'd either:

1. create 2 packages, one called mylibrary (a normal package) which contains your actual library code, and the other called mylibrary_plugins which is a namespace package.
2. or, create mylibrary.lib, which is a normal package and contains your code, and mylibrary.plugins, which is a namespace package.

Personally I'd use option 1.

The rationale section of PEP 420 explains why `__init__.py` cannot contain any code.

Comment: Eric, in case 2, `mylibrary` would have to also be a namespace package, correct?

Answer (score 1):

strictly speaking, you can *have* variables under `mylibrary`, you just won't be able to define them there.  You can, for instance:

```
# mylibrary/core.py
import mylibrary
def some_function():
    pass

mylibrary.some_function = some_function
```

and your users can use it like:

```
import mylibrary.core
mylibrary.some_function()
```

That is to say, `mylibrary.core` monkey patches `mylibrary` so that, other than the import, it looks as though `somefunction` is defined in `mylibrary` rather than a sub-package.